# Происхождение выражения «гриф секретности»

Tags: этимология, лексика

Из современной художественной литературы:

*– Это абсолютно секретные  сведения! Я давал клятву о неразглашении на клетке Грифа Секретности!*

*– Да, птичка серьезная. Клювом так долбанет – и не встанешь!*

***Гриф*** – хищная птица. Но это слово имеет и другие значения, в частности, известно выражение «гриф секретности». Каково его наиболее вероятное **происхождение**  и **когда** оно появилось в языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почин в деле защиты государственной тайны и уголовно-карательные меры за преступления связанные с разглашением, передачей или утерей важных государственных документов, шпионаж и прочие действия наносящие вред государству, принадлежит Германии (Германское Уложение 1871 года), примеру которой последовали Австро-Венгрия, Франция, Италия и Россия.
Постановлением СНК 24 апреля 1926 года был утвержден “Перечень сведений, являющихся государственной тайной”. Все сведения были разделены на группы по характеру содержания. Кроме того, было введены категории секретности, для обозначения которых использовались три грифа секретности: совершенно секретно, секретно и не подлежит оглашению.
https://studbooks.net/1162428/pravo/istoriya_stanovleniya_organizatsii_zaschity_gosudarstvennoy_tayny
О том, что документ может иметь особую пометку - «печатный гриф» есть и более ранние упоминания. Например, в Словаре церковно – славянского и русского языка 1847 г.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Если верить wiktionary, слово "гриф" в значении "пометка, надпись на документе, определяющие условия, правила его использования" происходит от немецкого "*Griff*". Последнее имеет значение "приём" или "захват" и связано с ощущением чего-либо на ощупь. Ещё есть значение "*Haftung von einer Oberfläche an einer anderen*", что можно перевести как "приклеивание одной поверхности к другой (как бы схватывание)". Может быть, эти пометки делали с помощью наклеек? Но это лишь версия.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.